# How can I manually delete or regenerate California Schedule D (540) in TurboTax?

Tags: united-states, taxes, capital-gains-tax, california, turbotax

How can I manually delete or regenerate California Schedule D (540) in TurboTax? I'd prefer not to have to start over the California tax section in TurboTax.

---

Motivation (TL;DR: incorrect cost basis for RSU sale on TurboTax-generated California Schedule D, even though I entered the correct cost basis in the 1099-B form):

I use TurboTax to file my taxes as a California tax resident. My [California Schedule D (540) ("California Capital Gain or Loss Adjustment")](https://www.ftb.ca.gov/forms/2019/2019-540-d.pdf) ([mirror](https://archive.vn/reX3K)) incorrectly indicates the "cost or other basis" for my  [restricted stock unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restricted_stock) sales are 0 USD, even though federal Form 8949 ("Sales and Other Dispositions of Capital Assets") indicates that the correct, non-0 "cost or other basis".

[This answer](https://ttlc.intuit.com/community/investments-and-rental-properties/discussion/ca-540-incorrectly-shows-0-cost-basis-for-rsu-sale/00/1184528) ([mirror](https://archive.vn/ckYPG)) by [primus1981](https://ttlc.intuit.com/community/user/viewprofilepage/user-id/1299001) explains that TurboTax is indeed inconsistent in the following case, and the fix is "manually deleting the form":

> A TurboTax CPA rep was able to help me resolve this.  It turns out that initially entering a cost basis of $0 was the problem.  This generated a CA Schedule D (540) that should only be filled out when the state capital gains/losses are different than the federal.  After I entered the correct cost basis, the D (540) was not automatically removed.  **Manually deleting the form fixed the issue**.

I had indeed initially entered a cost basis of 0 USD (because that's what the 1099-B form provided by E*Trade Securities LLC incorrectly stated), then later entered the correct cost basis:

[image]

[image]

so I match this case, which indeed results in an California Schedule D (540) incorrectly indicating that the "cost or other basis" for my  [restricted stock unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restricted_stock) sales are 0 USD.

As a result, I want to manually delete or regenerate California Schedule D (540) in TurboTax.

Note that according to [this answer](https://ttlc.intuit.com/community/taxes/discussion/answered-in-comments/01/190969#M77597) ([mirror](https://archive.vn/WokAV)) by  [Intuit employee TerryA](https://ttlc.intuit.com/community/user/viewprofilepage/user-id/85773), even though the California Schedule D (540) states "Do not complete this schedule if all of your California gains (losses) are the same as your federal gains (losses)", Turbotax still files it regardless of whether one's California gains (losses) are the same as one's federal gains (losses):

> Since Sch D is a gov't form it can't be set "for your records" so it prints out for filing as well. If mailing the Calif return in it doesn't hurt for it to be attached when it doesn't need to be. In your case you can leave it out since the FTB won't expect it to be there.
>
> This printing of the Sch D when line 8 is negative is because many TT users over the years have asked how to compute their Calif capital loss carryforward when the amount wasn't available from their prior year return. That can't be done without seeing the prior year Sch D.
> So it's a convenience for the users but can cause questions for astute users like you.

In my case my California gains (losses) are the same as my federal gains (losses) so I'm fine with either removing the California Schedule D (540) or regenerating it.

I don't see the California Schedule D (540) or RSU-related rows in my state section's rows that have an "edit" button:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer on https://ttlc.intuit.com/community/accessing/help/how-do-i-view-and-delete-forms-in-turbotax-online/00/25593 ([mirror](https://archive.vn/kifrA)):

> Here's the general procedure for viewing the forms list and deleting
> unwanted forms, schedules, and worksheets in TurboTax Online:
>
> 1. Open or continue your return in TurboTax.
> 2. In the left menu, select Tax Tools and then Tools.
> 3. In the pop-up window Tool Center, choose Delete a form.
> 4. Select Delete next to the form/schedule/worksheet in the list and follow the instructions

Visually, this gives:

1.
[image]

2.
[image]

3. Delete "Schedule D" and not Form 540.
   [image]

After deleting "Schedule D", TurboTax will automatically and silently (= no notification to the user) generate a new Schedule D with the correct cost basis (one can view the generated Schedule D in toolbar -> print center -> Print, save or preview this year's return -> 2019 California return).